# how to find if list elements are contained in other list without exact match

Tags: python

```
baseNames = ["this","that","howdy","hello","anotherfile"]
testList = ["this.txt","that.txt","howdy.txt","hello.txt"]

def _validateFilesExist(self):
    for basename in self.baseNames:
        self.baseNameCounter+=1
        self.logger.logInfo("Looking for file-> " + basename)
        for filename in self.testList:
                if basename  in filename:
                    self.counter+=1
                    self.logger.logInfo("File was found")
                #else:          
                #   self.logger.logInfo(basename)                   
    if self.counter != self.baseNameCounter:
        raise Exception("All files not avaialble")
    else:
        self.logger.logInfo("All files available")
```

OUTPUT:
[image: I like this output but Im trying to figure out how to get the last file that was not found to display "file not found"]

If i uncomment the else statement at the bottom , this is what the output looks like...

[image]

i really am only trying to get it to say file not found once obvuously if its not found. Just a little stuck on the logic . P.S. I dont want to use check for exact matches is and thats why I use the 'in' if condition when traversing.

Answer (score 0):

Convert both list to set and use minus would be a better solution

`diff_files = list(set(baseNames) - set(testList))`

And check `len(diff_files)` for your final purpose

Update 1:

Below code is the idea, it is not optimal possibly.

```
baseNames = ["this", "that", "howdy", "hello", "anotherfile"]
testList = ["this.txt","that.txt","howdy.txt","hello.txt"]
existed_files = list()
for basename in baseNames:
    for filename in testList:
        if basename in filename:
            existed_files.append(basename)
            break

if (len(existed_files) != len(baseNames)):
    raise Exception('Not all matched')
```

Update 2: Get only none existed files

```
baseNames = ["this", "that", "howdy", "hello", "anotherfile"]
testList = ["this.txt","that.txt","howdy.txt","hello.txt"]
not_found_files = set()
for basename in baseNames:
    found = False
    for filename in testList:
        if basename in filename:
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        not_found_files.add(basename)

if not_found_files:
    print('Not found files')
    print(not_found_files)
    raise Exception('Not all matched')
```

Comment: would minus work though if they arent exact matches?

Comment: Not It doesn't, it only use exact matches. I am giving you different solution to support that.

Comment: How could I get it to print WHICH file was not found?